# Data for previous year in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table with this structure:

| date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 |
| 2021-01-11 | 2 |
| 2021-03-18 | 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-01-03 | 4 |
| 2022-01-10 | 5 |
| 2022-01-17 | 6 |
| ... | ... |
| 2023-01-02 | 8 |
| 2023-01-09 | 9 |
| 2023-01-16 | 10 |

I need to get for each date "amount" a year ago:

| date | amount | year_ago |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | - |
| 2021-01-11 | 2 | - |
| 2021-03-18 | 3 | - |
| ... | ... | - |
| 2022-01-03 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-01-10 | 5 | 2 |
| 2022-01-17 | 6 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-01-02 | 8 | 4 |
| 2023-01-09 | 9 | 5 |
| 2023-01-16 | 10 | 6 |

I have tried to use `LEFT SELF JOIN` and window function with `RANGE`. But it doesn't work because
dates are little different with a day

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "a year ago" (sum of entire year? value of the date exactle a year ago? value of the date close the one a year a ago...). Please add expected output...

Comment: @S-Man
 have edited it in the lower table

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `LEFT JOIN` you can use:

- `- INTERVAL '1 year'` to subtract a year
- `+ INTERVAL '1 day'` to add a day

```
SELECT this_year.date_, 
       this_year.amount, 
       last_year.amount
FROM      tab this_year
LEFT JOIN tab last_year
       ON last_year.date_ = this_year.date_ - INTERVAL '1 year' 
                                            + INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tCPyPvNZbbPEeJ61AVicV/0).